# Return Value in a column based on value in a subset in another column

Tags: excel, set, element, match

I'm working on taking information from a table like so:

```
A    1
     2
B    3
     1
     4
C    2
     5
```

Essentially, a series of sets (A,B,C) with their elements arranged vertically beside them.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve the list of column 1 values that have a certain value in column 2. For instance, if the lookup value for column 2 was 1, I would want A and B to match, but not C. Best case scenario, I could generate a new column containing the matches. Is there a way to do this without resorting to VBA?

EDIT:
The data I am working with is not so clean, here's a doctored version of it

```
 1           2                  3      4

83    Fun Edit      ZZZZZZ*AAAAAA    210
                    365,400          176
                                     210
85    Fun Edit      600,500          205
                    MEDICARE[705]    176
                                     200
```

The extracted data does not like to preserve relationships between data beyond the column 1 identifier. In this case, the information in column 3 "###, ###" comes from item 176 in column 4. So filling down and taking the row will result in issues downstream.

In the long run, the data in column 4 is just a key for matching the information in this extract with another one.

I appreciate everyone's help thus far, and apologize for my insufficient original example.

Comment: Can you fill the letters down column 1 or are you stuck with the letter only being there for the first entry?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with the letter only being in the first entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short workflow that will do it:

1. Select the entire range
2. Press `Ctrl+G` (Goto)
3. Click `Special`
4. Tick `Blanks` and `OK`
5. Type `=` and `arrow up`. You should have a formula that looks like `=A1`
6. Press `Ctrl+Enter`. At this point all the missing alpha values should be filled in.
7. Apply `Autofilter` and filter the numbers to show only `1`
8. If you want to use the filtered alpha list elsewhere, copy the values showing, and paste elsewhere.

Comment: As I added above, this could create more problems than it helps down the line. However, this is of great use to me down the line! I wish I had the rep to vote this up!

Comment: If I understand correctly you could just select e.g. column 1 in the workflow.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I could just come back to the columns later if I ever need to look at the _###, ###_ values.